# save a variable that remains the value in all presentations

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to create a variable in powerpoint that remains don't matter what presentation I open.

I have created a variable using ActivePresentation.CustomDocumentProperties before and it works fine but the variable is created in the presentation so when you open a new presentation you cannot get this value. I need something similar but using Application expression so the value that you set is the same no matter what presentation you open.

Is that possible in powerpoint?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you'd want to save the value to the registry.  While you can call on the Win API to do this, it's a bit complicated and won't work if you run your code on a Mac.

Instead, use the built-in VBA SaveSetting and GetSetting commands.

```
Sub Thing()

' Save some values to the registry:

SaveSetting "MyApp", "Settings", "MySetting1", "MyValue1"
SaveSetting "MyApp", "Settings", "MySetting2", "MyValue2"
SaveSetting "MyApp", "Settings", "MySetting3", "MyValue3"
' Saves Setting/Value pairs to
' HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\VB and VBA Program Settings\MyApp\Settings

' Get one of the saved values:
Debug.Print GetSetting("MyApp", "Settings", "MySetting1")

' Get one of the saved values and return a default value if there's no such saved value:
Debug.Print GetSetting("MyApp", "Settings", "MySetting42", "The Answer To Life, Universe, et al")

' List
Dim lCount As Long
Dim MySettings As Variant

MySettings = GetAllSettings("MyApp", "Settings")

For lCount = LBound(MySettings, 1) To UBound(MySettings, 1)
    Debug.Print MySettings(lCount, 0), MySettings(lCount, 1)
Next

' Remove all of the settings:
DeleteSetting "MyApp", "Settings"


End Sub
```